# Iam facing a Visual Force error "Formula Expression is required on the action attributes."

Tags: javascript, custom-button, case

Hi I have developed a Custom close case button in java script however I face a Visual force error: Formula Expression is required on the action attributes.

Please find my script below

```
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/21.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/21.0/apex.js")} 
if({!ISPICKVAL(Case.Resolution_Area__c,'')}) { 
alert('Please fill resolution area'); 
}else if({!ISPICKVAL(Case.Have_you_consult_Tier_2_to_solving_this__c,'')}) { 
alert('Please fill "Was Tier 2 assistance required?"'); 
}else{ 
window.location = '/apex/CustomCloseCase?id={!Case.Id}'; 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this a VF Page or its a custom button on case detail

Comment: @tusharsharma It is a Custom button on the case Detail

Comment: The error seems completely unrelated to anything else in your post.

Comment: You should probably update the api levels on the REQUIRESCRIPT call - 21 is pretty old, given we are at 37 at the moment.

Comment: @SamuelRobert Is your page has any action attribute. If yes then then thats the issue.

Comment: @CasparHarmer@tusharsharma  This was the error I am facing in the sandbox, However I the Users do not have this issue in the prod. @Caspar I tried the version to 37.0 still Id throws the same error. The button functionality is to validate two field, when we hit on the close case It will verify two of those field as mentioned in the script and closes the case. One thing I noticed is when I hit Close case I was moved to the error page, however when i Go back to the case I see the case Status is updated as Closed.